# How to prevent directory browsing?

Tags: linux, apache

I wanted to disable directory browsing on my Apache server. I changed my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file to remove `Indexes`:

```
# Comment out old:
# Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
# New:
Options FollowSymLinks
```

I restarted Apache with `apachectl -k restart`.

However, this doesn't work as the directory listing is still possible.

I am running CentOS 5.8 linux and Plesk 11.

What to do?

Comment: To disable directory listing using htaccess you can use `Options -Indexes` read the full tutorial on  https://helponnet.com/2021/07/29/apache-disable-directory-listing/ disable directory browsing on Apache

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the Indexes option:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

You can simply put this line into `.htaccess` in your www root or in whatever folder you want all subfolders to deny listings.

or in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: How to do it via `httpd.conf`?

Comment: @Danijel: I edited my answer. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I can't try it right now, I resolved it by edditing `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @JensWirth there doesn't seem to be an httpd.conf file in Ubuntu 14.04? Where do I put this...? I also don't seem to be able to active .htaccess